# bind9 configure forward zone for local domain without DNSSEC for this zone only

Tags: bind, dnssec, dns-server

I have a working DNS server for local domain mydomain.local. I am trying to configure bind9 to work in default configuration, except for this zone, for which I want to forward queries to local DNS server. Here's config I have (ubuntu 14.04):

```
/etc/bind/named.conf.local:


zone "mydomain.local" IN {
    type forward;
    forward only;
    forwarders {
        192.168.1.1;
    };
};
```

But when I try to `nslookup server.mydomain.local` I'm getting following in syslog:

```
error (broken trust chain) resolving 'server.mydomain.local/A/IN': 192.168.1.1#53
```

It is my understanding that this is because of DNSSEC. I don't want to disable DNSSEC globally, but I do want to disable DNSSEC for this very zone. Is it possible?

Please do not suggest using `type slave;` zone. I want to achieve this with forward zone

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found an answer. Following line in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` fixes it:

```
--->        dnssec-must-be-secure mydomain.local no;   <---
```

So, full text of `/etc/bind/named.conf.options` will be (skipping comments):

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        forwarders {
                192.168.1.1;
        };

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-must-be-secure mydomain.local no;

        auth-nxdomain no;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

**UPDATE:** Actually, at this point I cannot tell if I indeed fixed bind with that line or didn't. Somehow all queries succeed now, with or without this line. If an expert is present here, please chip in

Comment: This answer only works if you have `dnssec-validation` set to `yes`, if its set to the default `auto` then it won't work

Comment: For me it works also with dnssec-validation auto;

Answer (score -1):

But if you create a zone "local",  the parent zone for "mydomain.local" and designate as ns the ip of the server you forward.this will make dnssec function with value auto.

More details https://netfuture.ch/2014/10/adding-your-fritzbox-as-a-secure-dns-resolver-for-the-fritz-box-pseudo-domain/