# Bind service doesnt reply with local domain

Tags: bind, dns-hosting

My setup is the following

ServerA (vpn-server with 10.200.0.1) has a Bind9 service running on VPN ip range.

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";

  forwarders {
    8.8.8.8;
  };

  dnssec-validation auto;
  auth-nxdomain no;

  listen-on {
    10.200.0.1;
  };

  allow-query { any; };
};

controls {};
```

The local zones are defined as followes:

```
# named.conf.local 
zone "domain.tld" {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/db.domain.tld";
};
```

and zone db.domain.tld is like:

```
$TTL  6800
@ IN  SOA servera.domain.tld. root.domain.tld. (
           13   ; Serial
          600   ; Refresh
        86400   ; Retry
       604800   ; Expire
       604800 ) ; Negative Cache TTL
;
; name servers - NS records
     IN      NS      servera.domain.tld.

; 10.200.0.0/24 - domain.tld
servera.domain.tld.    IN      A      10.200.0.1
root.domain.tld.       IN      A      10.200.0.1
x.domain.tld.          IN      A      10.200.0.2
```

It contains some local domains (domain.tld). When I use nslookup on my notebook (which is connected to VPN), it works as expected.

```
# nslookup
> server 10.200.0.1
Default server: 10.200.0.1
Address: 10.200.0.1#53
> x.domain.tld
Server:     10.200.0.1
Address:    10.200.0.1#53

Name:   x.domain.tld
Address: 10.200.0.2
```

When I create a second bind service on my local side (192.168.1.1) that is connected via VPN to ServerA and only define this in `/etc/bind/named.conf.options`:

```
options {
  directory "/var/cache/bind";

  forwarders {
    10.200.0.1;
  };

  dnssec-validation auto;
  auth-nxdomain no;

  listen-on {
    192.168.1.1;
  };

  allow-query { any; };
};

controls {};
```

and try to use this service as just a forward dns to the external dns, I don't get answers for all domains configured within serverA, but all public DNS responses

```
# nslookup
> server 192.168.1.1
Default server: 192.168.1.1
Address: 192.168.1.1#53
> x.domain.tld
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

** server can't find x.domain.tld: NXDOMAIN
```

As already said. Both Bind server can make public DNS lookups like google.com. But, why doesnt ServerB get answers for domain.tld from ServerA, but when I use nslookup in the same network, it works.

Because ServerA doesnt know about ServerB I didnt configure any upstream DNS server. I wonder why ServerB cannot query domain.tld but google.com or something else public.

PS: be aware that domain.tld (especially .tld is a private TLD like ".home"), so there is no public root server.

Answer (score 0):

I think, I found the issue.

When I change `dnssec-validation` on ServerB to `no`, I'm getting an answer.

... adding some more infos later, when I know how to add the DNSSec for domain.tld... til then have a look at [bind9 configure forward zone for local domain without DNSSEC for this zone only](https://serverfault.com/questions/670411/bind9-configure-forward-zone-for-local-domain-without-dnssec-for-this-zone-only) which is currently not my best solution, because I'd like to configure ServerB without any knowledge about hosted domains on ServerA.